# Cloud SQL Connection Limits with Google APP Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Does anybody knows how can we use more than 12 concurrent connections from App Engine to the Cloud SQL?

We found that the documentation says:
"Each App Engine instance running in a standard environment cannot have more than 12 concurrent connections to a Google Cloud SQL instance."

We're using Java for App Engine using Hibernate... The connection pooling states that it shouldn't be used in production environment but if we disable the pooling we reach the max number of connections.

Comment: Using App Engine Flexible Environment instead?

Comment: @JL-HN because we're using Task Queues... But for the next iteration we'll probably move to the flexible environment.

But isn't there a way to solve this? Maybe getting a bigger instance of the Cloud SQL?

Comment: @JCRRamirez it looks the limit comes from App Engine instead of Cloud SQL as you can see "Each App Engine instance running in a standard environment cannot have more than 12 concurrent connections to a Google Cloud SQL instance." under the 'Google App Engine Limits' section at https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Google Cloud FAQ: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps

> Google App Engine Limits
>
> Requests from Google App Engine applications to Google Cloud SQL are subject to the following time and connection limits

- For apps running in the Google App Engine standard environment, all database requests must finish within the HTTP request timer, around 60 seconds. For apps running in the flexible environment, all database requests must finish within 24 hours.
- Offline requests like cron tasks have a time limit of 10 minutes.
  Requests to Google Cloud SQL have limitations based on the scaling type of the App Engine module and how long an instance can remain in memory (residence).
- Each App Engine instance running in a standard environment cannot have more than 12 concurrent connections to a Google Cloud SQL instance.